# Syntax Error running on Python

Tags: python, blockchain

I'm trying to follow the blockchain tutorial which is in JS but I'm trying it on Python.

I've got this far and when I'm trying to test run it, I get this syntax error which is confusing me since it seems legit.

Any thoughts?

```
import hashlib

class block:

def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous= ''):
    self.index = index
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.data= data
    self.previous = previous
    self.hash = ''

def calculateHash(self):
    return hashlib.sha256(self.index + self.previous + self.timestamp+ (self.data).__str__()

class blockchain:
#btw this it where it says the error is: "class"
def __init__(self):
    self.chain= [self.createGenesisBlock()]

def createGenesisBlock(self):
    return block(0, "01/01/2017", "Genesis Block", "0")

def getLatestBlock(self):
    return self.chain[len(self.chain)-1]

def addBlock(self, newBlock):
    newBlock.previous = self.getLatestBlock().hash
    newBlock.hash= newBlock.calculateHash()
    self.chain.push(newBlock)

korCoin  = blockchain()
korCoin.addBlock(block(1, "10/07/2017", 4))
korCoin.addBlock(block(2, "12/07/2017", 40))

if __name__ = "__main__":
print(korCoin)
```

Comment: `if __name__ = "__main__":` you need a double `=` here

Comment: Count the parentheses on the previous line to where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis:

`hashlib.sha256(self.index + self.previous + self.timestamp+ (self.data).__str__()`
`hashlib.sha256(self.index + self.previous + self.timestamp+ (self.data).__str__())`

I am assuming you have properly indented your actual code but pasted it with wrong identation in the OP. That's why the first answer asks you to fix indentation.

There are other issues with the code

- `self.index` is an integer, you have to convert it to string before concatenating with others. You can not concatenate a string and integer
- `self.previous` is an empty string(`'') in the first`korCoin.addBlock` call but is a Hash object in the second call. You have to convert it to string or retrieve its string representation before concatenating with others
- `self.chain` is a list and list doesn't have `push` method. I suppose you meant `append`

Answer (score -1):

The functions in your class all have wrong indentation. Try this -

```
import hashlib

class Block:

    def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous= ''):
        self.index = index
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data= data
        self.previous = previous
        self.hash = ''

    def calculateHash(self):
        return hashlib.sha256(self.index + self.previous + self.timestamp+ (self.data).__str__()

class BlockChain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain= [self.createGenesisBlock()]

    def createGenesisBlock(self):
        return block(0, "01/01/2017", "Genesis Block", "0")

    def getLatestBlock(self):
        return self.chain[len(self.chain)-1]

    def addBlock(self, newBlock):
        newBlock.previous = self.getLatestBlock().hash
        newBlock.hash= newBlock.calculateHash()
        self.chain.push(newBlock)

korCoin = BlockChain()
korCoin.addBlock(block(1, "10/07/2017", 4))
korCoin.addBlock(block(2, "12/07/2017", 40))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(korCoin)
```

Follow python's indentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)

Comment: Can someone tell me why the down vote?

Comment: You were right but it was that I posted it wrong. The actual code was indented correctly and the error was elsewhere as @Shiva mentioned. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then please post your question correctly with all the information available to you like "errors" so we don't get confused